# I need to calculate the sum correctly for the three calculated columns

Tags: postgresql

I need help with my query, where the **total** of 3 counted columns in one column as total, here is my current query:

```sql
SELECT region, COUNT(s_code), COUNT(b_code), COUNT(d_code), SUM(COUNT(s_code, b_code, d_code)) as total
FROM shilpy
GROUP BY region 
ORDER BY region
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the total, you can just sum it up inline:

```
SELECT region, 
       COUNT(s_code) + COUNT(b_code) + COUNT(d_code) AS total
FROM shilpy
GROUP BY region 
ORDER BY region
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to calculate specific counts, and then get the total of counts without having to rescan the entire table again:

```
select *, (count_s + count_b + count_d) as total
from (
  select region, count(s_code) as count_s, count(b_code) as count_b, count(d_code) as count_d
  from shilpy
  group by region 
  order by region
) as s;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/sCpFSBeh)